# OpenGL : Rotate using roll pitch and yaw values

Tags: opengl, rotation

I have an issue of rotating my model. I have file that are composed of relative interger values for roll, pitch and yaw. 
Thus every period of time I read those values and applie to my model :

```
rotate(current_yaw - previous_yaw, QVector3D(0,0,1)) ;
rotate(current_pitch - previous_pitch, QVector3D(0, 1, 0)) ;
rotate(current_roll - previous_roll, QVector3D(1,0,0)) ;
```

The rotate function multiplies the transformation/model matrix with a rotation matrix. 
My issue is that when the values go back to 0, the model is not straight.

I tried doing one rotation only (only the yaw, then the roll, then the pitch) and it works fine. So the issue is with combining the rotations.

I know that order matters. I would like to do, for instance, roll - pitch - yaw and afterwards yaw - pitch -roll to get back to the initial position of the model.
But in case of thousands of non symetric values, where some angles may be positives and others negatives, I don't really know what to do.

Is there a way to apply all those rotation at the same time ?

Edit : 
To try and apply all the rotations at the same time I tried using QQuaternion. Here is an example of what I though would work but still does not.

```
    QQuaternion rotation = QQuaternion::fromEulerAngles(20, 20, 20) ;
    m_world.setToIdentity();
    m_world.rotate(rotation);

    QQuaternion rotation_back = QQuaternion::fromEulerAngles(-20, -20, -20) ;
    m_world.setToIdentity();
    m_world.rotate(rotation_back);
```

The world matrix is not identity in the end.

Edit : of course the second quaternion should be (0,0,0)... I need to use angles not differences of angles. Works fine.

Comment: Are you accumulating the rotations in a transformation matrix? If so, when the values go back to 0, does not mean the accumulated matrix also goes back to 0.

Comment: Yes I'm applying those rotations to the transformation matrix, and no it does not go back to 0 and that is my issue. 
That's because, I believe, when applying yaw(20°) - roll(20°) - pitch(20°) and afterwards in the same order yaw(-20°) - roll(-20°) - pitch (-20°) the model does not go back to it's initial attitude because the axis have changed, and thus the transformation matrix does not go back to 0. 
I'm looking for a way to go around this...

Comment: Store the angles as angles and simply compute your rotation matrix every frame. You could also consider quaternions.

Comment: I though what you suggested would indeed solve my probleme but oddly it doesn't. I've edited my post with what I tried.

Comment: The inverse of rotation (20,20,20) is not (-20,-20,-20). Don't think of them as two vectors that cancel each other out, they are two sets of euler angles rotated in a certain order. The inverse to rotation of euler angles (20,20,20) would be something approximately (-13.468, -24.770, -13.467). Please specify what is it exactly you are trying to do with these angles.